# Is there a simple way to create stacked notifications in GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome, notification, notification-area

For example notify-send will create a new notification icon in the tray every time it's executed. I haven't been able to find an easy, preferably scriptable, way of creating these.

[image: Example of a "stacked notification"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`notify-send` will only create a new notification. However, there are various bindings for `libnotify`, e.g., to Python (package `python-notify`). Check out the example provided with the package for replacing the text in a notification:

```
python /usr/share/doc/python-notify/examples/test-replace.py
```

Extending this to appending text should be straightforward.